# Getting data from API but can't do anything with it

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I'm trying to learn to code android apps with kotlin. I want to display some data that i get from the api(https://api.kuroganehammer.com/api/characters). I generated the data classes using the JSON to kotlin plugin in IntelliJ.

Logcat shows that i'm getting the Data however it doesn't trigger the onResponse method.

I tried debugging but can't really find anything other than for some reason the onFailure and onResponse methods are ignored.

ApiRequest:

```
fun fetchAllCharacters(): Call<CharacterApiRequest>
```

CharacterApiRequest:

```
    @SerializedName("character")
    val characters: List<Character>
)
```

Characters(Fragment, gets called in onViewCreated()):

```
            .enqueue(object : Callback<CharacterApiRequest> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<CharacterApiRequest>, t: Throwable) {
                    //Display an error to the user, because there was a io exception
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<CharacterApiRequest>, response: Response<CharacterApiRequest>) {
                    //We got a response
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        //Bind the data only when we have it
                        response.body()?.apply {
                            adapter.setData(this.characters as MutableList<Character>)
                        }
                    } else {
                        //Display an error
                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: the possible error would be JSON parsing!

Comment: @KishoreJethava i'm not getting an error message for some reason. The Api returns a list of objects which fit in the data class 'Character'

Comment: T (generic type of your Callback) should be of a *response* and not the *request*. In your case just change your callback's generic parameter from `CharacterApiRequest` to `List<Character>`.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the callback's generic parameter from CharacterApiRequest to List worked, as stated in the comment from @MateuszHerych